# Is an EMF more/same/less in an insulator than in a conductor?

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, insulators

Is an EMF (electromotive force) more/same/less in an insulator than in a conductor?

For example: A loop of copper and a loop of plastic in a changing magnetic field.
In which will the emf be the greatest?

Comment: Same emf, different currents.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

emf exists in a closed path in space irrespective of the presence of a material medium. The presence of a conductor thus allows a path for electrons to flow.

Answer (score 0):

EMF induction depends on change of flux or condition of motional emf if the conditions are same then emf induction is same for all material as faraday's law is being followed irrespective of material medium.

Answer (score 0):

The part of net emf due to external magnetic field is the same. However, net emf in the case of conductor includes also contribution due to self-induction when current is changing in time. In plastic this should be negligible. So net emf will be different if current is changing in time in the copper ring.